# AWS API Gateway Cognito Authorization simulation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

I have just starting learning developing AWS serverless apps and I have this problem.

I have created a serverless app composed of APIGW and Lambdas. For authorization of APIGW, I have chosen Cognito Identity Pools using Google Federation. Is it possible to test this without a UI component? what I want to do is test the whole api authentication and authorization process via Postman.

Without a UI, I could not authenticate via google and get an id token. I need to pass this id token to my authentication endpoint to retrieve the AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey from Cognito. I will then pass the AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey to my APIGW calls in postman.

Is there a way to get the ID token from google? without using UI codes. Something like manually pass my google credentials plus the app client id to google so that it would return to me a valid id token.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get an authenticated id token from google is to go through authentication flow. Doing otherwise would present some security issues. What you could do is create a Cognito user pool with its own mapping to cognito identity roles and fetch credentials using the AWS API from there.